# How can I get the number of undelivered messages (metric api) present in Pubsub using python client library?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am using Pubsub as a queuing mechanism tool and want to know the count of the messages residing inside the topic of Pubsub. For the same purpose, I have decided to use the Google API metric `pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/num_undelivered_messages` but I am unable to figure out how can this be achieved using python client library monitoring_v3.

```
from google.cloud import monitoring_v3
import time,os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/key.json"

client = monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient()
project = 'project_name'
project_name = client.project_path(project)
metric_type = "pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/num_undelivered_messages"
```

Can you please guide me on how to proceed further and query this google api metric named as num_undelivered_messages?

Comment: I am using Google Cloud client library which has been mentioned in the following link for Stackdriver monitoring https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/reference/libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me but I am not sure if it's the creator's intention.

```py
from google.cloud import monitoring_v3
from google.cloud.monitoring_v3 import query

project = "..."
client = monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient()
result = query.Query(
    client,
    project,
    'pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/num_undelivered_messages',
    minutes=1).as_dataframe()
```

Comment: Can you suggest, how to filter it for specific subscription?

Comment: you can filter later on as `result` is a dictionary with a key for subscription name

Answer (score 1):

You might need to run your code this way for a specific subscription:

```
from google.cloud import monitoring_v3
from google.cloud.monitoring_v3 import query

project = "my-project"
client = monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient()
result = query.Query(client,project,'pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/num_undelivered_messages', minutes=60).as_dataframe()

print(result['pubsub_subscription'][project]['subscription_name'][0])
```

Comment: Thanks :) so will it give the messages which are 60 minutes old?